# How can I pipe Content of a webapi call to a file?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi method that returns an xmldocument.   I would like to execute my webapi call in a batch cmd file and pipe that content to a file so I can ftp the xml doc to a vendor.  so basically I want to do something like this:

```
 c:> http:\\localhost\api\GetDocument\counterparties > c:\counterparties.xml
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

use cURL , free download at http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

```
C:>Curl http://localhost/api/...  > somefile.txt
```